# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AnyView'

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, kingfisher

we are facing the issue after updating the Xcode 14.3

/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName/ dhfelfdsyohhzxfkhlcejfrdx/SourcePackages/checkouts/Kingfisher/Sources/SwiftUI/KFImageRenderer.swift:48:63 Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AnyView'

Comment: Looks like it's now need to update Kingfisher.

Comment: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/releases/tag/7.6.1

Answer (score 17):

I used to have the same problem.

pod 'Kingfisher', '7.6.1'

And then pod install, you can solve the problem.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Swift Package Manager,

- Open Package Dependencies and double click on the Kingfisher
- Change the version as 7.6.2
- Done!

Answer (score 1):

Just click in UPGRADE PACKAGE Kingfisher at the left menu.

Comment: What is the additional insight you contribute beyond what other existing answers already mention? Please [edit] fo make that more obvious, ideally according to [answer].

Answer (score -2):

if you are using cocoa pods, verify your configuration and run
`pod update`